# Refreshing NSTableView in inactive NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nswindow

I have an application with a primary window and a floating window with a tableview in it. When I modify in the primary window the input for the floating window (which makes the floating window inactive or not key) then the tableview does not show the new data in spite of calling reloadData: on the tableview.

I also tried refreshing the floating window (since it contains the tableview) with the following (without success):
    [[window contentview] setNeedsDisplay:YES];

So, the question basically is how to refresh a tableview in a window that is not the frontmost window, inactive if you will.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without code we can only guess...
My guess is that the data you are modifying in the main window could not be the same as the floating window. (It could be a copy for example.)
just a guess...

Comment: The code is spread over half a dozen files, but let me elaborate about the problem. The datasource of the tableview in the floating window does get updated, but the window (and tableview) is not. So the problem lies with refreshing the window when it is not active (or not the key window) and simply reloading the tableview does not solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I was seeing similar behavior and could not find a solution.  Here's what solved it for me:

Make sure that you are updating the tableview in the floating window on the main thread. I was updating my NSOutlineView in response to a notification and didn't realize the notification was being posted on a background thread.  The outline view did not get updated until I activated its containing window.

Once I moved that code to the main thread, it started working correctly.